# laravel-8: Why i cannot install Laravel/Breeze

Tags: laravel, breeze

When I tried to install laravel breeze, using command `composer require laravel/breeze --dev`, it gives me this error:

```
Using version ^1.2 for laravel/breeze
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/breeze
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/breeze[v1.2.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require illuminate/filesystem ^8.42 -> found illuminate/filesystem[v8.42.0, v8.42.1, v8.43.0, 8.x-dev] but it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/breeze ^1.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/breeze[v1.2.0, v1.2.1, 1.x-dev].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

My current version of laravel : **laravel8**.

I'm trying to add an users's authentification session on an existing application.

My **composer.json** file :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.2",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
```

Comment: Is that all of the requirements in your `composer.json` file? Seems you have a package that has a conflict with `illuminate\filesystem`.

Comment: yes !! it is the all of the requirements in the `composer.json` file. The fact is that the error message does not show which package is in conflict with `illuminate\filesystem`

Comment: Try running `composer update -w && composer dumpautoload` then try installing breeze again.

Comment: Nice !! it is resolved. thanks

Comment: hey @Peppermintology I tried the same but after it still giving the same error while trying to install laravel/breeze:

Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/breeze[v1.2.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require illuminate/filesystem ^8.42 -> found illuminate/filesystem[v8.42.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/breeze ^1.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/breeze[v1.2.0, v1.2.1, 1.x-dev].

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your dependencies listed [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#updating-dependencies)

Maybe you will not find "laravel/ui" in your composer.json, if it's the case add to it manually as a property from the parent "require".

Then you have to save the file and run on the terminal the command: `composer update`

Follows below my composer.json file for reference:

```html
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.3",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0|^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Laravel UI is a legacy package that was replaced with laravel/breeze. Why would you need  laravel/ui installed when installing laravel/breeze? They are mutually exclusive by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Also,composer installed laravel breeze version 1.21,but I need to change it to 1.11,because 1.21 it's totally different than 1.11,need it to change blade components in /resources/views/components

Answer (score 0):

The solution that has worked for me using Laravel 9.

```
composer require laravel/breeze:* —-dev
```

It is the only one that has worked for me since it will install the appropriate version according to your dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

Best solution:

- delete composer.lock file
- Go to composer.json and add to "require" this: "laravel/breeze": "^1.1",
- run composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
- It's done
- Your composer.lock file will generated again including installation